# What is this syntax called? `new Type() { ... }`

Tags: java

I know that Java will let you do trickery with a variable's type when initializing a class variable. Along the lines of:

```
SomeType foo = new SomeType() {
    {
        this.fooField = 12345;
    }
    @Override public void someMethod() {
        throw new ReallyWeirdException();
    }
};
```

which will create an instance variable `foo` where `someMethod()` has different semantics than in the usual `SomeType`, and where `fooField` is initialized to a value other than its normal default.

But what is the `new Type() { ... }` syntax called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anonymous Inner Class.

You define a class (class) inside your code (inner) that has no name (anonymous) but inherits from SomeType, then override some of its methods and properties.

Comment: Ah, right, thank you! Much easier to read up on it when you know what you are looking for. :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's called an anonymous class declaration, see [the spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.9).

Answer (score 2):

You have

1. a anonymous class (`new SomeType() { ... }`) and
2. a initializer block (for `fooField`).

Answer (score 2):

I think that the term you are looking for is [anonymous classes](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Defining a class inside a method is a type of inner class; see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd call this an anonymous (sub)class.

Note that you are doing two things here - over-riding someMethod in your anonymous subclass, and also adding an instance initializer (which is setting fooField to a new value)

Comment: Yes, I know that it's doing two things. Initializer blocks are useful sometimes. (Although I realize now that for the purpose of the example, I probably should have omitted one of them.)